# save requests and headers to file

Tags: r, http, http-headers

I'd like to save the URL's of all network requests from a given session and also the headers. I'm clueless on how to do this (one way would be using Chrome to manually right-click save each requests response and copy the headers which would be extremely time-consuming). I wonder if I need something like Charles/Fiddler or I need some code? If the latter is true I'm only proficient in R.

Comment: "given session"… session from where?

Comment: I meant just Internet browsing period by session

Comment: If you use Chrome, try right click, copy as HAR in the Network tab after reload

Comment: But that is per request not per all requests

Comment: Gotcha. So, Fiddler, Burp (an unfortunate name), etc is the way to go. You'll need to proxy all requests through them then export the results to HAR, JSON, XML.